# Keeping an elements width static after removing another element while still remaining responsive

Tags: html, css, less

I have a button with some text in it and when a user presses the button I replace it with a loading symbol. When I remove the text inside of the button and replace it with the spinner, the button shrinks.

I have created a [fiddle of the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/maxshuty/n98f6vks/1/).

I know that I can simply add a fixed width to the element, however the page is responsive all the way down to 300 pixels. I also know I can add media queries to address this, but I'm wondering if there is any easier way via LESS or vanilla CSS to handle this without all the media queries?

Here is my basic setup:

```
<button>
  <span class="hidden-conditionally">
    Click here to perform an action!
  </span>

  <span id="spinner" class="displayed-conditionally">
    Loading...
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the min-width of that "button" to 100% (or whatever floats your boat really).  That way, the button would be forced to occupy the same amount of available space offered by any parent element regardless of the content within the button:

```
<button style="min-width:100%">
  <span class="hidden-conditionally">
    Click here to perform an action!
  </span>

  <span id="spinner" class="displayed-conditionally">
    Loading...
  </span>
</button>
```

This fix need not be an inline style attribute, it can also be added in an associated .css file as well.